# Method overloading with types int and long, which method will get called and when?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am having two methods `int Add(int, int)` and `long Add(long, long)`.

When I call this method the call gates resolved on the basis of the size of the parameter I am passing to these method.

How does C# compiler identifies which method to call?
I guess it resolves with size of the parameter which we are passing to the method.
if parameter size fits in datatype(int) it will call `int Add(int, int)` otherwise it will call `long Add(long, long)`.

This is my guess, please conform the same and clarify how call to these methods got resolved?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.Add(2, 3);
        p.Add(223232323777, 3);
    }

    long Add(long a, long b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read: [7.4.2 Overload resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: `2` is parsed as an integer, `223232323777` is parsed as a long. Integers can be implicitly converted to longs, but not the other way around due to data loss. So yes, 'size' is involved somehow, in that it prevents implicit conversion from long to int, but not in the sense of 'memory size'.

Comment: There is also the return type.  long answer = p.Add(2, 3); will call the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is true. As long as both numbers fit into an `int` the second method is called. The second parameter is implicitely converted to `long` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) to match the signature.

You can also force the use of the first method for a smaller number:

```
Add((long)2, 3);
```

or

```
Add(2L, 3);
```